# How to get the img src of website having spaces in their class name with simple_html_dom.php?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Actually, i am try to get the image source of first product of this website. but the problem is

"The image has space in their class name ".
like this: `class="_396cs4  _3exPp9"` .

[Website here:](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Iphone%2012%20pro%20max&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off)

i have tried code like this to get the image src. but it's not working:

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Iphone%2012%20pro%20max&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off');

$element = $html->find('img._396cs4._3exPp9',0)
echo $element->src;

?>
```

After this, i am not getting actual image src of first product.
how to solve this?

Comment: fyi "_The image has space in their class name_" - that would mean it is _two_ classes

Comment: I could not find any img with a class of `_3exPp9` on that url

Comment: @broomeer it is the class of image of first product. just hover on that image. it shows class name like:```img._396cs4._3exPp9 ```

Comment: Take a look at the source code, search for `_3exPp9` and don't find anything. Hover over the second image, inspect -> it has the same class. `_3exPp9` is most likely a class used when hovering images

Comment: Do u have any idea then how to get the product image src. i am getting src in ```svg``` format. i want in ```.png``` format. so it can be displayed later.

Comment: just give me the idea to get the exact product image src?

Answer (score 2):

The `_3exPp9` class is not present in the original HTML, it's added with client-side JavaScript. The Simple HTML DOM library operates on raw HTML, it does not include a JavaScript engine.

```
<img class="_396cs4" alt="APPLE iPhone 12 Pro Max (Pacific Blue, 128 GB)" src="//static-assets-web.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_fcebae.svg"/>
```